# Gnuplot script for several files

Tags: bash, matrix, plot, gnuplot

I have a file with large data set from which I need to extract a table. I have done for a single file with gnuplot

```
set contour
unset surface
set cntrparam levels discrete 0.5
set table "DATA_1.txt"

splot "TEST_DATA_1.dat" matrix
```

Now, I have several files with name "TEST_DATA_*.dat" and just would like to generate several tables like DATA_i.txt with all other files.

```
set contour
unset surface
set cntrparam levels discrete 0.5

do for[i=1:1500] {
   set output sprintf("DATA%d.txt",i) 
   splot sprint("TEST_DATA_%d.dat" matrix, i)
   }
```

I have tried with i iterations to generate DATA_i.txt files..but it doesnt work.. Can someone point out what is wrong

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What does "it doesn't work" mean? This is too unspecific. You probably get some error messages or undesired output or whatever. 
First of all the command is called `sprintf`, and next is the closing bracket is at the wrong location. Check `help sprintf`.

I would try:

```
splot sprint("TEST_DATA_%d.dat",i) matrix
```